# Error when writing to destination table

Tags: google-bigquery

When running a query from Web UI with Destination table i get this (very unclear) error: "An internal error occurred and the request could not be completed".
When running the same query without destination (return results to screen) it runs fine. I manage also to save the results as table from the screen.

Is there any known problem?
can someone please suggest a workaround?

(Job ID job_aCixvJwkYMkCUTqnsvN4B5Kt430)

Comment: As you may already guess, there should be some problem with your "destination table". Maybe there is a "schema incompatibility" issue. If you can share more details about your destination table & the query, more help will surely come.

Comment: this is a new destination table, with overwrite (hence, no schema issue). the query runs fine when returning to screen (hence, no query issue). I do hope the Google guys can indicate something according to the Job ID.

Comment: Hi N.N... this error is an internal query engine bug; we're currently investigating.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is an internal error in the query execution engine. Since this query was run, we've updated to a newer version that should not exhibit this problem.

Can you try again and let me know if you still encounter the issue? If so, please provide an updated job id.